# Login page is verifying all users as good Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to build a login page in Django. But whenever I try to authenticate the user it doesn't work. The user passes each time even if the user doesn't exist. Any help I would really appreciate it!

```
def login(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)

    form = CreateUserForm()
    return render(request,
                  "leadfinderapp/login.html",
                  context={"form":form})
```

Answer (score 0):

The user isn't actually getting authenticated, you just aren't handling errors in the form. The function is just rendering the `"leadfinderapp/login.html"` template again regardless of the user's data entered.

To handle errors in the form, you need to have a

```
if form.is_valid():
    # submit information and login
else:
    # re render form with errors
```

You should look into using Django All Auth to handle your authentication (https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) it's customizable but handles a lot of the work for you - just like Django itself!